# Make sorted representation of dict of lists

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a dictionary of lists like

```
dict = {'p1':[a,b,c,d,f]}
```

where

- `a` and `b` are `mx.DateTime.DateTime` objects i.e. time;
- `c` and `f` are `mx.DateTime.DateTimeDelta` objects i.e. result of operations between `a` and `b`;
- `d` is a boolean value.

I want to write some value from the dictionary in a file in a sorted by time order:

```
for key in dict:
        f.write(key+'  ')
        f.write(str(dict[key][4]))
        f.write('\n')
```

But I can't figure out how would I sort this by `dict[key][4]`. How can I make it?

Comment: maybe look into ordered dictionaries
https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure to understand your question but here is one way you can create a list of sorted keys:

```
dic = {'p1':[0,0,0,0,7], 'p2': [0,0,0,0,5], 'p3': [0,0,0,0,8]}
sorted_keys = sorted(dic, key=lambda k: dic[k][4])
print sorted_keys
# ['p2', 'p1', 'p3']
```

PS: please do not use `dict` as a variable name since it is a built-in type in Python

Answer (score 2):

`dict` by nature are data structure which does not keep order of their items (key:value) pair, so, if you want to write a sorted value from your dictionary, here is one way:

```
>>> dt = {'p1':[1,2,3,4], 'p2':[2,1,4,3], 'p3':[4,3,2,1]}
>>>
>>> sorted(dt.items(), key=lambda x:x[1][1])
[('p2', [2, 1, 4, 3]), ('p1', [1, 2, 3, 4]), ('p3', [4, 3, 2, 1])]
>>> 
>>> sorted(dt.items(), key=lambda x:x[1][2])
[('p3', [4, 3, 2, 1]), ('p1', [1, 2, 3, 4]), ('p2', [2, 1, 4, 3])]
>>>
>>> sorted(dt.items(), key=lambda x:x[1][3])
[('p3', [4, 3, 2, 1]), ('p2', [2, 1, 4, 3]), ('p1', [1, 2, 3, 4])]
>>>
```

Then you can loop through it to write to your file:

```
>>> mylist = sorted(dt.items(), key=lambda x:x[1][3])
[('p3', [4, 3, 2, 1]), ('p2', [2, 1, 4, 3]), ('p1', [1, 2, 3, 4])]
>>> for item in my_list:
        f.write('{} - {}'.format(*item))

#Output will something like:
#p3 - [4, 3, 2, 1]
#p2 - [2, 1, 4, 3]
#p1 - [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

On the other hand, if the order of items matters to you within your dictionary, then I suggest to you to use [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) from `collections` module:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> 
>>> 
>>> dt_orderd = OrderedDict()
>>> 
>>> for k,v in sorted(dt.items(), key=lambda x:x[1][3]):
        dt_ordered[k] = v


>>> dt_orderd
OrderedDict([('p3', [4, 3, 2, 1]), ('p2', [2, 1, 4, 3]), ('p1', [1, 2, 3, 4])])
>>> 
>>> 
>>> dt_orderd['p1']
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

This will create a dictionary as yours but at the same time it will maintain the order at which its items where inserted in the first place (during the `for` loop in this case)

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your dict into a list using `dict.items()`, as dict cannot be sorted.

This returns a list of tuples `[('p1':[a,b,c,d,f])]`

On that list, you can access `element[1][4]` to retrieve the `f`

You can apply that to a sort:

```
for key, value in sorted(dict.items(), key=lambda element : element[1][4]):
    f.write('{0}    {1}\n'.format(key, value[4]))
```